# swagger UI for url encoded form data in the request body for string type generates curl command with ascii values

Tags: python, flask, swagger-ui, connexion

Using the following versions for my flask python project:
connexion==2.3.0 swagger-ui-bundle==0.0.5 OAS 3.0

this is my swagger.json

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.0",

    "servers": [
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8080"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://localhost:8081"
    }
    ],
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "API",
         }
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/api/hvp/v1/calls/{call-id}/js": {
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "Post request"
                ],
                "operationId": "abcd", 
                "parameters": [
                    {
                    "name": "call-id",
                    "description": "call id",
                    "in": "path",
                     "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                     },
                    "required": true
                    }
                ],
                "requestBody": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/requestBodies/customEventBody"
                },
                "responses": {
                    "204": {
                        "description": "NO CONTENT"

                    },
                    "400": {
                        "description": "Bad Request",
                        "content": {
                                  "application/json": {
                                              "schema": {
                                                  "type": "object",
                                               "properties": {
                                                   "status":{
                                                     "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "detail": {
                                                    "type":"string"
                                                  }
                                             }
                                       }
                                  }
                             }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "requestBodies": {
            "customEventBody": {
                    "description": "url encoded form data ",
                    "content": {
                            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":{
                                   "schema": {
                                             "type": "object",
                                             "properties": {
                                                 "document": {
                                                   "type":"string"
                                                 },
                                                 "application":{
                                                   "type": "string"
                                                 }
                                    }
                            },
                            "encoding": {
                                 "document": {
                                       "allowReserved": true
                                         },
                                 "application": {
                                       "allowReserved": true
                                         }
                                }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
      }
}
```

as per the OAS 3.0 specification I have set encoding attributes to allowReserved= true,

but I still see the curl command output that is shown in swagger UI -> tryOut option with ascii values for parenthesis and double quotes as follows:

Actual result is this:
curl -X POST "http://v-jay-hvp-install:8080/api/hvp/v1/calls/fdfd/js" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "application=sss&document=%7B%22Property1%22%3A%22value1%22%7D"

Expected result is this :
curl -X POST "http://v-jay-hvp-install:8080/api/hvp/v1/calls/fdfd/js" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "application=sss&document={"Property1":"value1"}

What am I missing in swagger.json

Comment: Swagger UI does not support the `encoding...allowReserved` attribute for form data. Please open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Comment: Thanks Helen, I have this opened - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5597